# Reason behind dependence of forces on the medium

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, newtonian-gravity, dielectric

I am a high school student and have covered basic concepts in electrostatics, magnetism and gravitation. It is clearly stated in my text book that the gravitational force experienced between two bodies is independent of the medium. Whereas electrostatic and and magnetic forces are heavily dependent on the medium. Is this just the basic nature of gravitational force or is there a logic behind why  it remains unaffected?

Comment: Because the electrons in the medium get affected by the electric field themselves and hence they produce their own version of electric field. While in case of gravity, nothing like this occurs.

Comment: The particles in the atmosphere have mass and are hence affected by gravitational fields and they too produce their own versions.

Comment: they are too small to produce any thing of their own version.